# Is there a publicly available code or add-on to display a Cookie Policy banner like Stack Overflow's on my WordPress site?

Tags: cookies, privacy-policy

I'm trying to implement Cookie Policy banner on my WordPress web site and I really like visually the one Stack Overflow is using. Does someone know is it their custom solution or some kind of add-on code available to the public?

[Cookie Policy banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EFN9.png)

Thank you!

I tried using WP plugins but none of them were even close to what I wanted.